# Synchronization software with tree view, moved files detection and possibility to ignore file size

Tags: file-synchronization, synchronization

I am looking for a synchronization tool with the above-mentioned features.

I would love to use [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/) due to its unparalleled and simple user interface and incredible speed. Unfortunately, FreeFileSync does not allow to ignore the file size when comparing files. [GoodSync](https://www.goodsync.com/) is also excellent, but does not allow ignoring file size either.

I have also tried Syncovery and Bestsync. With both, however, the user interface is unfortunately daunting, and many features of FreeFileSync are missing.

So I'd be grateful for tips for synchronization tools that are as similar as possible to FreeFileSync, at the same time having all features mentioned in the subject.

FreeFileSync:
[image: FreeFileSync Screenshot]

GoodSync:
[image: GoodSync Screenshot]